# Simple drag and drop application not working

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsview, nsbox

I am trying a simple drag and drop application:

1. I am creating a CameraIconView (subclass of NSView, containing some image views, text fields and a pop-up button), at run time.
2. This view is enclosed within CameraIconEnclosingBox (subclass of NSBox)
3. Requirement is: user should be able to drag CameraIconView at some other location in CameraIconEnclosingBox.

To implement my requirements I am doing this:

1. Implemented following method in CameraIconView class-

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)e{

```
    NSPoint location; 
    NSSize size;
    NSPasteboard *pb = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CameraIconContainer"];

    location.x =  ([self bounds].size.width - size.width)/2;
    location.y =  ([self bounds].size.height - size.height)/2;

    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    [pb declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:IconDragDataType] owner:self];
    [pb setData:data forType:IconDragDataType];
    [self dragImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"camera_icon.png"] at:location offset:NSZeroSize event:e pasteboard:pb source:self slideBack:NO];
}
```

2. Implemented following method in CameraIconEnclosingBox class-

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:IconDragDataType]];
}
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender{
    return NSDragOperationEvery;
}
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender{
    return YES;
}
- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender{
    NSPoint dropLocation = [sender draggingLocation];

    float x = dropLocation.x;
    float y = dropLocation.y;
    NSLog(@"dragOperationConcluded! draggingLocation: (%f, %f)",x,y);

    NSPasteboard *pb = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    NSLog(@"Pasteboard name- %@",[pb name]);
    NSData *draggedData = [pb dataForType:IconDragDataType];

    CameraIconView *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:draggedData];
    NSLog(@"object - %@ / cameraNo : %@/ operatorName : %@",object,[[object cameraNo] stringValue],[[object operatorName] stringValue]);
    // the cameraNo and operatorName are properties defined within CameraIconView class
    // the above log is returning (null) for both properties

    float width  = [object frame].size.width;
    float height = [object frame].size.height;

    NSLog(@"width - %f / height - %f",width,height);
    [object setFrame:NSMakeRect(x, y, width, height)];
}
```

After implementing these methods I am able to perform drag but drop operation is not working, although all dragging delegate methods in CameraIconEnclosingBox are called.

Can anyone suggest where I may be wrong or some other better way to implement my requirements?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve it by adding this line of code:

```
[self addSubview:object];
```

before this code:

```
[object setFrame:NSMakeRect(x, y, width, height)];
```

So CameraIconView now is appearing at dropped location. :)

... but now I am facing a new problem-

> each time the CameraIconView is
>   dragged and dropped, it is not
>   positioning the dragged CameraIconView
>   to new location, but is creating and
>   showing a new instance within
>   CameraIconEnclosingBox at new location, ie. for the
>   first drag and drop two icons start
>   appearing for the same CameraIconView
>   ... for second drag and drop three
>   icons start appearing and so on....

Can anyone suggest me some way to resolve it?

Thanks,

Miraaj